# Correspondence Theorem for maximal ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ a ring and $J$ a ideal of $R$. Show that $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ if, and only if, $\overline{M}=M/J$ is a maximal ideal of $\overline{R}$.

Proof: Lets suppose $M$ maximal. So, if $\overline{I}=I/J$ is a ideal of $\overline{R}$ that contains properly $\overline{M}$, i.e., 
$$\overline{M}\subsetneq \overline{I}$$
We need to show that $\overline{I}=\overline{R}$.  In fact, since 
$$\overline{M}\subsetneq \overline{I}$$
we have
$$M\subsetneq I$$
But, since M is a maximal ideal of $R$, this implies that $I=R$. Then, $\overline{I}=\overline{R}$. Therefore, $\overline{M}$ is a maximal ideal of $\overline{R}$.

Conversely, lets suppose $\overline{M}=M/J$ is a maximal ideal of $\overline{R}$. So, if $I$ is a ideal of $R$ that contains properly $M$, i.e., 
$$M\subsetneq I$$
We need to show that $I=R$. In fact, since $J\subset M$ (by correspondence theorem), we have $J\subset I$. So, we have 
$$\overline{M}=M/J \subsetneq I/J=\overline{I}$$
But, since $\overline{M}$ is maximal ideal of $\overline{R}$, we have $\overline{I}=\overline{R}$. This implies that, $I=R$. Therefore, $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

My question is: How to generalizes this proof for simple groups? Thank you.

Comment: You should assume at the beginning that $J\subset M$, otherwise it's not clear what $M/J$ means.

Comment: Also, can you write down what you want to prove in the context of simple groups explicitly? This will help us answer that question directly, keeping this argument as reference.